# How to make website accessible to non-mobile devices only?

Tags: php, html, web, localhost

Is there any method so that i could disable my hosted webpage for mobile phones.  the website which i host must be accessible only through laptop or pc . Any user who accesses the hosted website must get a message so as to open the website from a windows browser. Is there any php or script to do this

Comment: check the user agent and redirect appropriately?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177456/how-to-disable-access-to-website-for-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/dmolsen/Detector

> Detector is a simple, PHP- and JavaScript-based browser- and feature-detection library that can adapt to new devices & browsers on its own without the need to pull from a central database of browser information.